# Makefile not linking to one of the header files in one sub-directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile with the following directory structure -

**Example** - Contains *Makefile*, main.c, xyz.c, xyz.h and sub-directories *Hal* and *Interrupt_Config*
**Hal** - Contains *test2.c* and *test2.h*
**Interrupt_Config** - Contains *try.h*

Below is the Makefile I am using-

```
EXE    := practice
CC     := gcc
CPPFLAGS := -IHal -IInterrupt_Config
VPATH  := Hal:Interrupt_Config

MAIN_OBS  := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
INT_OBS  := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard Interrupt_Config/*.c))
HAL_OBS  := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard Hal/*.c))
ALL_DEPS := $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(MAIN_OBS), $(HAL_OBS), $(INT_OBS))

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(MAIN_OBS) $(HAL_OBS) $(INT_OBS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -o $@ -MD -MP $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

-include $(ALL_DEPS)

clean:
     rm -f $(EXE) $(MAIN_OBS) $(INT_OBS) $(HAL_OBS) $(ALL_DEPS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Whenever I am trying to do *make* without including Interrupt_Config/try.h it works absolutely fine . My *main.c* includes are like this -

```
..
#include "test2.h"
#include "xyz.h"
#include "try.h" // Problem is here
..
```

and *try.h* is very simple like this -

```
#ifndef TRY_H
#define TRY_H

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#endif
```

But the moment I use values of *TRUE* or *FALSE* anywhere in *main.c* and try to do *make* again. It throws me error - **'TRUE' undefined (first use in this function) and similar for 'FALSE'.**

I am not able to understand what exactly is the problem, since I am new to Makefiles.

**EDIT**

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test2.h"
#include "try.h"
#include "xyz.h"

int main()
{
    bugs(); //test2.h
    bunny(); //test2.h
    t_print(); // xyz.h
    printf("Yes! your age is %d\n",TRUE); // try.h
}
```

Comment: Does it say that can't find the `try.h`?

Comment: you don't have, by any chance, TRY_H as multiple inclusion guard in any of the other header files do you?

Comment: @EugeneSh. no it doesn't complaint about not finding try.h

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk I have verified no other files contains such thing.

Comment: Add a `#message` or `#warning` to `try.h` to make sure it is included. If it is, someone is undefining the FALSE and TRUE somewhere after the inclusion..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know how to do that. Let me check then.

Comment: You are actually aware that there is a boolean type in C since C99? Just `#include <stdbool.h>` and you get the C++-names `bool`&friends.

Comment: Just add a line `#message "Yay! Try.h is included"` to the `try.h` file near the TRU/FALSE definitions.

Comment: @Olaf Those were just included for testing purpose, I know that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it throws an error invalid preprocessing directive #message in Interrupt_Config/try.h . So it does gets included.

Comment: Well, it wasn't the idea :) But good enough. Actually it should be `#pargma message`. Well, I guess you will have to post your `main` here.

Comment: do you, by any chance, #undef TRUE or #undef FALSE in any of your headers / sources? out of curiosity I created the directory structure with empty files but try.h main.c (main.c just references TRUE), and this makefile worked. i think problem might be somewhere else

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk No I have cross checked everything

Comment: Do you have two headers `try.h`?  Why not use `#include "Interrupt_Config/try.h"` in the include line?

Comment: It's probably time to zip up all your files and post them here so that others can reproduce your error and see what is wrong.  Also, what version of gcc and what operating system are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would definitely want to go for that but it is not dependent on me. The team I am working with wants it like that. You can assume it's my assignment to do this.

Comment: I tried creating such folder structure and dummy files with only the code you shared, I was unable to reproduce the problem. I agree with @DavidGrayson

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk.. I just rewrote 'same' files and 'rewrote same' Makefile. It worked this time. Don't know what was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrote every file including Makefile it worked this time, Not sure what was the issue since everything seemed okay.